# Style css module not applied [React + Webpack]

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am discovering the CSS modules in a react application, I also use Webpack.

I edit the webpack configuration file, I try to change the color of a paragraph using a css file to test but the style is not applied.

Visual studio code tells me that the module is not found but I have yet entered the correct path of the file.

I think it's a problem with the webpack configuration file.

I did a lot of research, I tried different solutions ...

I thank you in advance for your help and your answers

I tried to follow the tutorial of this site => https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/

I did research on stack overflow, I try several solutions proposed in the different posts but it still does not work.

I then check with the webpack documentation to add the loaders "style-loader" and "css-loader"

Webpack configuration file

```
module.exports = {
   entry: [
      './src/index.js'
   ],
   output: {
      path: __dirname,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
       {
         enforce: 'pre',
         test: /\.js$/,
         loader: 'standard-loader',
         exclude: /node_modules/
       }, {
         test: /\.js$/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         exclude: /node_modules/
       }, {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
       }
     ],
     loaders: [{
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
       },{ 
          test: /\.css$/, 
          loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
       extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','css']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
   }
 };
```

File CSS

```
.title {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 124px;
 }
```

Test code snippet

```
 import styles from './home.css';

 <p className={styles.title}>hello world</p>
```

I want to change the color of a paragraph, using a CSS module but the style does not apply to the refresh of the page.

Comment: your webpack contains similar loader configs twice, once using the new (webpack 3+) syntax _module.rules_ and once the old syntax _module.loaders_. Get rid of the latter, let's see if this solves your problem

Comment: Yes indeed, I tried a lot of things, basic I had the syntax loaders so I delete the rules, it still does not work.

Comment: OK, wanted to exclude this from the possible causes of the problem

Comment: Try setting the _modules_ option: `use: [ 'style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } } ]`

Comment: I need to add these lines in module.loaders syntax?

Comment: No, remove the _module.loaders_ section, if you use a current version of webpack, that doesn't do anything. Replace `use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ]` in the _module.rules_ section with the code I've posted

Comment: After adding this line, I get this error in my terminal after starting with npm start : ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modules":true}!./src/containers/home.css
Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Comment: OK, seems like the config is correct now, but webpack can't find your CSS file. Probably for the same reason why VSCode complains. Sorry, I don't know how else to help you, perhaps someone else has an idea.

Comment: Looks like an error related to css-loader, thank you for your help.